# Logging into a website using requests (website seems to use RSA)

Tags: python, python-3.x, encryption, cryptography, python-requests

Usually I have no issues logging into website using requests, but this one I just can't figure out what I need to input into the password field. I can log into it fine using selenium with headless Chrome, but I need to be able to login with requests.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

session = requests.Session()
e = int('10001', 16)
r = session.get("http://hwwi-rohindex.de/")
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,'lxml')
n = soup.find(id='rsa_n')['value']

payload = {'user': 'username', 'pass': 'password', 'submit': 'Anmelden',

           'logintype': 'login', 'pid':'7963', 'tx_felogin_pi1[noredirect]': 0, 
           'e': e, "n": n}

session.post("http://hwwi-rohindex.de/index.php?id=7946", data=payload)
```

I *think* the values for 'e' and 'n' that I am passing are correct, but they could be wrong as well. The password is not simply passed on but is somehow encoded and this is the part that is throwing me off, as far as I can tell.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Furthermore, when I run your code it finds no tags on that web page with an `id` attribute of `rsa_n`.

Comment: i need to login into this website using the requests module. the code that I posted works as-is (in terms of getting the rsa_n value via bs4), both on my work machine and at home. If you need any specific info please ask specifically

Comment: Ok, I copy and pasted the code above and again no such value was found. Perhaps someone else will have better luck.

Comment: could be bs4 version difference - the only thing I can think of. thanks for trying at least.

Comment: StackOverflow is not a site to offload your work. Can you describe how the authentication is supposed to work? If the page changes their authentication procedure then this question would lose all value and won't be reproducible for future readers.

Comment: Eh? I don't know how the authentication is supposed to work, this is why I asked the question. Also, how am I offloading my work?